# Java: how to write more text in a text file after the already written text

Tags: java, text

I want to write in atext file incrementally, that is, write the first String, then the program should check that there is text and should go to next line to write the next string etc.

Any ideas?

I was thinking that somehow the program should check whether there is something written in the file and go to the first blank line. But I have no idea, with which statements to do that.

Alternatively, I can just add everything in a String and print it all together in the end.But I would prefer the first option..

Answer (score 4):

You need to open file with append mode.  For example

```
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathtoFile, true);
   fos.write("Your new content".getBytes());
```

Comment: @squaleLis Its been awhile, so I might have added that as comment there. Irrespective, you are correct that you can't directly write String, it should be bytes. Updated answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically first check if a file is empty, if not then append your content to the end of the file.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path_to_File"));     
if (br.readLine() == null) {    //checks if file is empty
System.out.println("File is empty");
}
```

Then to append to the file you can do something like this:

```
FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
bWriter.write(data);
```